# Get pre-selected value of an HTML select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

Or through example, how can one retrieve "c" via JavaScript or jQuery no matter if the user changed it?

```
<select id="select-menu">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c" selected>C</option>
    <option value="d">D</option>
</select>
```

I tried the following, however, it returns the value of the currently selected menu. I suppose I can take a similar approach which runs upon page load and save the value, but expect there is a more "proper" way to do so.

```
$('#select-menu > option').each(function(i){
    if(this.selected) {
        console.log(this.value)
         $("#submit").val(this.value);
         return false;
    }
})
```

Comment: So you want to get "C" regardless of what the user selects? Why not just hard code that into whatever you are using it for?

Comment: @DrydenLong  If an event happens, I wish to go back to the original state without reloading the page.  I can hard code it if necessary, but doing so is prone to forgetfulness.

Comment: Read the value just after JS is parsed. Before user has had the chance to modify it.

Comment: I see now, you mention getting the value on page load, and that would work. The other option is to give the option you want as the default a class of `.default` or something and getting that value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery .attr() to get initial value:

```js
function get_initial(){

    $('#select-menu > option').each(function(i){
    
        if($(this).attr('selected')) {
            console.log('initial: ' + this.value)
        }

        if(this.selected) {
            console.log('current: ' + this.value)
        }
    
    })

}

$('.initial').on('click', get_initial);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select-menu">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c" selected>C</option>
    <option value="d">D</option>
</select>

<button class="initial">check initial</button>
```

Comment: I guess it does work.  I was just using javascript, and now see that jQuery behaves differently.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no better way. A select is meant to be user-modifiable.

If you want to retain the original value you could save it on load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var initialValue = $("#select-menu").val();
});
```

You could also write it in a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="initial-select-menu" value="c">
```

This way has the benefit that the value will be submitted along with the rest of the form. Might be preferable in some cases.

Or you could stuff that initial value in a `data` attribute:

```
<select id="select-menu" data-initial="c">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c" selected>C</option>
    <option value="d">D</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastien,  Will stop looking.  I will probably store it in `data` associated with the use.

Comment: Love the `data` attribute idea, probably the best way to go about it

Comment: Yes I think `data-` is the cleanest, but you can't automatically submit it.

Comment: No need to submit.  jeprubio's answer also works, and directly returns the value. That being said, I will actually be doing how you recommend.

Answer (score 1):

You could save the value on an html5 data-* attribute:

```
<select id="select-menu" data-default="c">
```

And get it with

```
$("#select-menu").attr("data-default");
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code exhibits various examples related to getting of values from select fields using JavaScript.

**Working Snippet**

```js
const selectMenu = document.getElementById("select-menu");

var selectedIndex = selectMenu.options[selectMenu.selectedIndex].value;

/*Option 1*/
selectMenu.onchange = function() {
  selectedIndex = selectMenu.options[selectMenu.selectedIndex].value;
}

/*Option 2*/
/*selectMenu.addEventListener("change", function(){
  selectedIndex = selectMenu.options[selectMenu.selectedIndex].value;
})*/

/*Option 3*/
/*function updateSelectedIndex() {
  selectedIndex = selectMenu.options[selectMenu.selectedIndex].value;
}*/

document.writeln(selectedIndex);
```

```html
<!-- Option 3 -->
<!-- <select id="select-menu" onchange="updateSelectedIndex"> -->
<select id="select-menu">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c" selected>C</option>
    <option value="d">D</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the appropriate cases:

```
 let preselectedOption = $(targetDropDown).find('option[selected]');
 let currentOption = $(targetDropDown).find('option:selected');
```